# Uploaded images broken with secure site turned on

Tags: 6

Images I upload through CCK appear broken, the path they are referenced to is blocked with secure site.  When I view the image I am taken to the secure site login page, once I enter my login info I can view the image. But I am already logged in. The strange thing is sometimes one of these uploaded images is visible. Uploaded images have the following url structure.

All permissions are set correctly and only these images are blocked by Secure Site.

/sites/default/files/imagecache/142x142/imagefield_default_images/def_expert_4.png

/sites/default/files/imagecache/142x142/def_expert_4_19.png

sometimes one url works sometimes the other

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Imagecache functionality, first URL is your actual size image, the second is your Imagecached image, Imagecache creates seperate image sizes depend on your image-styles that you defined so it can loads the proper image when you print it.

about the login issue, it must be because of your [Secure Site](https://drupal.org/project/securesite) module configuration

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I understand why the urls are different, and am pretty sure also that it has to do with Secure Site config, only I can not figure out why.